# Jsp Search By Criteria

Tags: javascript, sql, database, jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="entity.Membership"%>

<!-- retrieve session object, memList -->
<%
List<Membership> memList = (List)session.getAttribute("memList");
%>

<!-- Display Member -->
<fieldset>
<form action="SMemberId.jsp" align="right">
     <input TYPE="text" name="id" class="textbox" placeholder="Seach Member By ID">&nbsp;
     <input type="SUBMIT" value="Search"/>
    </form>
 <legend><strong><font color="White"> Member List </font></strong></legend>
 <div style="height:245px;overflow:auto;">
<table border="1" width="100%" height="auto" align='center' bgcolor="#00d2ff">
 <tr >
    <th>Member ID</th>
    <th>Member Type</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>IC</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
     <th>Member Fees</th>
</tr>
<% for (Membership membership: memList){ %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= membership.getMemberid()%></td>
        <td><%= membership.getMembertype() %> </td>
        <td><%=  membership.getName() %></td>
        <td><%=  membership.getIc() %></td>
        <td><%=  membership.getPhone() %></td>
        <td><%=  membership.getAddress() %></td>
        <td><%=  membership.getGender() %></td>
        <td><%= membership.getFees() %> </td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

## Servlet

```
package controller;

import entity.MemService;
import entity.Membership; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class SearchMember extends HttpServlet {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        MemService memService = new MemService(em);
        List<Membership> memList = memService.findAll();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("memList", memList);
        response.sendRedirect("membership/DisplayMember.jsp");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SearchMember.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the     left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
```

}

Currenly i just can display a table from the database.i have 10 entity in there.
Can i ask How do i search data by criteria that mean what i type it ,it will come out automatically .
I no idea how to search by criteria . Example i type M001,the table will auto come out the member with M001 or i type by gender M ,will list all Gender M.so where i need to create the text field and search? it needs javascript to do what?

Comment: Do a Google search for refreshing a table using JQuery AJAX.

Comment: because currenly i have 1 search text field,and whatever i type in if same value with the database,it will come out the table only

Answer (score 0):

You question as it stands is too broad. There is no magic solution that will just do it.

You need to start with a basic solution and then enhance it from there. You can easily update your Servlet to add some basic search functionality by updating your request handler as below to search by name, for example.

Once you have this working you will want to look at searching by other fields. Maybe a dropdown where the users selects the field they wish to search on. After you have done all of that you can look at using Ajax to update the table on keystroke.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        MemService memService = new MemService(em);
        List<Membership> memList;

        if(request.getParameter("name") != null){
            memList = memService.findByName(request.getParameter("name"));

        }else{
            memList = memService.findAll();
        }

        request.setAttribute("memList", memList);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("membership/DisplayMember.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SearchMember.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

And your form:

```
<form align="right">
     <input type="text" name="name" class="textbox" placeholder="Seach Member By Name">&nbsp;
     <input type="SUBMIT" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

Comment: i saw my lecturer do that.but i don't know what is the solution for that.